# How do I handle an exception thrown for an undefined function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my infamous validation directive, below, I pass the name of a required validation function as parameter to the attribute based directive:

```
MyBigApp.directive("mlNgValidations", function ($compile) {
    var valAttributes = {
        phoneNumber: function (element) {
            element.attr("ng-pattern", "/^[0-9]+$/");
            element.attr("ng-minlength", 5);
            element.attr("ng-maxlength", 8);
        }
    }

    return {
        priority: 10000,
        terminal: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var validationType = attrs.mlNgValidations;
            valAttributes[validationType](element);
            element.removeAttr("ml-ng-validations");
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

If I declare an element with a mispelled validation function, e.g:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ml-ng-validations="phooneNumber" />
```

I get the non unexpected exception:

> TypeError: valAttributes[validationType] is not a function

I would like a more informative message at least, preferable without having to define a new exception, maybe something like:

> TypeError: Validation function phooneNumber is not defined

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, where you appear to own the code which is calling the non-function: don't. An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.

```
MyBigApp.directive("mlNgValidations", function ($compile) {
    var valAttributes = {
        phoneNumber: function (element) {
            element.attr("ng-pattern", "/^[0-9]+$/");
            element.attr("ng-minlength", 5);
            element.attr("ng-maxlength", 8);
        }
    }

    return {
        priority: 10000,
        terminal: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var validationType = attrs.mlNgValidations;
            var fn = valAttributes[validationType];

            if (typeof fn !== "function") {
                throw new Error("Validation function " + validationType + " is not defined");
            }

            fn(element);
            element.removeAttr("ml-ng-validations");
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

If you don't own the calling code, you can use the regular `try .. catch` if you own some code which encloses the calling code. For something like this, that seems unlikely, and you're stuck with ugly, browser-specific hacks like Firefox's [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror). That will at least let you catch the exception and examine it, possibly re-throwing it as your own, more descriptive error. That doesn't seem worth the effort to me.

Comment: I was only really worried about conveying to a designer that they have named an undefined function, which the default exception doesn't narrow down much, but maybe I should just log that and allow the normal course of action for any exceptions.

Comment: @ProfK Personally, this is a situation where I'd throw the exception as above, via early detection. This is the kind of thing that should only come up during development, and I wouldn't trust myself to notice a log message. On the other hand, I'll definitely notice if my app stops working. (If you want to get really crazy, perform those checks when the fields load instead of waiting for a value to be entered, in case the designers don't test very well.)